# Mostrar solo los nombres de usuario que comienzan con determinada letra en la cláusula where

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo una lista ordenada por letras alfabéticas, que básicamente devuelve usuarios registrados en la tabla de contactos. Estoy tratando de hacer que la búsqueda devuelva solo usuarios que comiencen con la letra correspondiente, es decir, que devuelvan nombres que comiencen con la letra A en la columna A de la página y así sucesivamente hasta que el alfabeto termine.

Pude buscar, pero no pude evitar que los nombres que comienzan con otra letra aparezcan en la columna incorrecta, Sigue mi código para que los amigos puedan ver lo que se puede hacer:

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $user_name = Auth::user()->name;
    $contacts = DB::table('contacts')->where('name', $user_name)->get();
    return view('home', compact('contacts', 'user_name'));
}
```

View

```
                   <div class="p-2">
                    @if(isset($contacts))
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <!-- Alphabet with number of contacts -->
                        <li class="pt-3 pb-3 sticky p-3 b-b white">
                            <span class="badge r-3 badge-success">Y</span>
                        </li>
                        @foreach($contacts as $contact)                              
                        <!-- Single contact -->
                        <li class="my-1">
                            <div class="card no-b p-3">
                                <div class="">
                                    <div class="image mr-3  float-left">
                                        <img class="w-40px" src="assets/img/dummy/u1.png" alt="User Image">
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <strong>{{$contact->first_name}}</strong>
                                        </div>
                                        <small> {{$contact->email}}</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                     @endforeach                                
                    </ul>

                     <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <!-- Alphabet with number of contacts -->
                        <li class="pt-3 pb-3 sticky p-3 b-b white">
                            <span class="badge r-3 badge-success">Z</span>
                        </li>
                        @foreach($contacts as $contact)                                  
                        <!-- Single contact -->
                        <li class="my-1">
                            <div class="card no-b p-3">
                                <div class="">
                                    <div class="image mr-3  float-left">
                                        <img class="w-40px" src="assets/img/dummy/u1.png" alt="User Image">
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <strong>{{$contact->first_name}}</strong>
                                        </div>
                                        <small> {{$contact->email}}</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                     @endforeach

                      @else
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info btn-block">+ Adicionar novo contato</button>                          
                    @endif;
               </div>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Debes usar like en tu clausula where.

Comment: gracias! Esperaré las respuestas. sobre el uso de la cláusula where ('like', 'B%'), si alguien duda por qué no funciona aquí, siga el error: 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `like` = ?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where ('like', 'B%')` estabas cerca con esto, te faltó el nombre del campo,

```
public function index($letra)
{
    $contacts = DB::table('contacts')->where('name', 'like', $letra.'%')->get();
    /*
        Seri mejor que definas un Modelo para la tabla y tu consulta seria:
        $contacts = \App\Contacts::where('name', 'like', $letra.'%')->get();
    */
    return view('home', compact('contacts'));
}
```

El cual tendras que invocar como

```
Route::get("usuario/{letra}","Controlador@index");
```

De esta forma pasamos la `letra` con la cual va buscar la `lista`

Comment: gracias! Suena funcional, pero ya sabes lo que sucede, les muestro a estos usuarios en una especie de barra lateral, en el menú de autenticación, debe estar en el controlador de arranque, de lo contrario, devuelve un error, habría una manera de hacerlo sin tener que solicitar una URL. ? solo llevarlo de todos modos, me ayudó mucho, ¡salvó el día!

Comment: Quiero decir, ¡cargar automáticamente sin tener que hacer una solicitud de URL sería perfecto!

Comment: si usas modelos puedes imprimirlo directamente en la `vista` `<?php ?>` dentro de la sintaxis pones `$contacts = \App\Contacts::where('name', 'like', $letra.'%')->get();` y ya los tienes, claro, `$letra` tendrias que poner uno por defecto